# Chrome extension VoIP app audiostream not playing continuously when user switch tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In VoIP app once I open extension and call is ongoing while switching tab or clicking extension again audio get stopped I want it to be played continuously untill call is not ended

I tried to store audio stream in chrome storage band retrieve it in content script but chrome do not store it also I auto play audio stream in content script by sending message from background service worker manifest v3 chrome 119